# how to make an inner join with mongodb and mongoose and nestjs?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, nestjs

I have a system with mongodb genericized by mongoose in nest js how do I bring customer and product data in the same request

in the database the data is like this:

```
  "_id": "621d2137abb45e60cf33a2d4",
        "product_id": [
            "621cedbf79d68fb4689ef0cb",
            "621cedbf79d68fb4689ef0cb",
            "621cedbf79d68fb4689ef0cb"
        ],
        "client_id": "621d19f890ec693f1d553eff",
        "price": 597,
        "__v": 0
```

my serviçe:

```
  findAll() {
    return this.sealsModel.find().exec();
  }
```

This way didn't work:

```
findAll() {
    var a = this.sealsModel.find().exec()
    return this.sealsModel.aggregate([{
        $lookup: {
          from: 'seals',
          localField: 'client_id',
          foreignField: '_id',
          as: 'client' 
        }
    }])            
    .exec()
}
```

but return this:

```
 "_id": "621d3e0a1c3bcac85f79f7cc",
        "product_id": [
            "621cedbf79d68fb4689ef0cb",
            "621cedbf79d68fb4689ef0cb",
            "621cedbf79d68fb4689ef0cb"
        ],
        "client_id": "621d19f890ec693f1d553eff",
        "price": 597,
        "__v": 0,
        "client": []
```

Comment: Have you checked Mongoose's function `populate` ? See: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html

Comment: @JrmDel this? this.sealsModel.find().populate({ path: 'client', select: 'name' })

Comment: @JrmDel trying this but not work

Comment: Have you tried without the exec(), the aggregate already invoke it.

Comment: @avisiboni the clients  also return empty

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to Mongo's `$lookup` operator is Mongoose's `populate` function. In order to use it properly, you first have to update your model.

You should have a client model that looks like this:

```js
// /models/Client.js
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const clientSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  _id: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
  ... // the rest of your fields
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Client', clientSchema);
```

The key thing to notice here is the last line. The model is referenced as "Client".

The change you have to make is mainly in your `Seal` model :

```
// /models/Seal.js
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const sealSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  _id: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
  client_id: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "Client" // We use the same name we gave to our client model in the last file
  }
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Seal', sealSchema);
```

Then, in your code, you should be able to use:

```js
const Seal = require("YOUR_PATH/models/Seal.js")

Seal.find().populate("client_id")
```

One important side note: your model shows the mongo ID as a string

```
"_id": "621d3e0a1c3bcac85f79f7cc",
"client_id": "621d19f890ec693f1d553eff", <---
```

Make sure that the field `client_id` is of type `ObjectId` or it won't work:

```
"client_id": ObjectId("621d19f890ec693f1d553eff")
```

Comment: I did exactly as you said but got the same error:
 ERROR [ExceptionsHandler] Schema hasn't been registered for model "clients".
Use mongoose.model(name, schema)

Comment: https://github.com/Rodrigobrinate/stock-system-backend 

my code

Comment: Well, you use TypeScript, my solution works for JavaScript, I didn't notice since it was not specified in your tags. I might be limited to help you here unfortunately. Have you searched for this specific error elsewhere in SO ?